# QT get Current Loggin User ID

Tags: c++, qt

In c# can do this using Process.GetCurrentProcess().SessionId.. to get current login user Ids in Windows
IN QT how can we do this ?

[image]

Comment: It could be operating system specific. On what OS?

Comment: There's no Qt API for this AFAIK. Just use Win32 API, like you would from a non-Qt native C++ program.

Comment: In Microsoft Windows only ..

Comment: There's no way to do this in QT. This is specific to Windows, so you'll have to call Windows API to do this, and you've already been given an answer which explains how to do it. I've flagged your question as a duplicate.

Comment: ok so i will use c# to get this information thanks friends for helping me..

Comment: @AnkurTripathi It might be best if you just delete this question, and possibly improve the other one (like put that image there) to illustrate what problem you have with C++ answer there. But Qt code is C++ code, so just include the relevant Windows headers, and call the relevant Windows API functions.

Comment: @hyde unable to delete

Answer (score 0):

You should use WinAPI.

What you used in C# is just sugar, wrapper for that, because C# created to work with Windows.
Maybe what you need is GetCurrentProcessId method, you can find it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms683180(v=vs.85).aspx).

But if you need only yours ID, you can use qint64 QCoreApplication::applicationPid().

Comment: Please improve this answer to actually contain the relevant information without clicking the link. While MSDN links are pretty stable, this answer should still remain useful if it happens to break for some reason.